# vim pasting lines by option

Tags: vim, copy-paste

I want to paste two different lines in two different cases:

In case A, I want to paste  "This is case A" and in case B, I want to paste "Completely different case B".

If I use yy and p, only one line could be remembered.
Is there a simple way to do such a thing like this:

Just a example:

```
1) Ctrl+F1+yy copies in buffer F1, Ctrl+F2+yy copies in buffer F2

2) Ctrl+F1+p pastes the line in buffer F1 and Ctrl+F2+p pastes the line in buffer F2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vim is perfectly suited for this - it comes with its own set of slots, called *registers*.

You can access the last, previous-to-last, etc. deleted or yanked contents by prefixing the `p` paste command with `"0`, `"1`, etc.

Alternatively, you can use 26 named registers `a` - `z`; explicitly yank / delete into them via `"ayy`. The `:registers` command lists the current contents.

Read more at `:help registers`.